# why am I getting "Error in checkName: Must use single string to index into reactivevalues."

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a simple logging app that takes a number of user inputs and appends them to a table that is displayed to the left. the following two R scripts are the same in structure but when I run the proof-of-concept version it works fine while the fleshed-out version returns "Error in checkName: Must use single string to index into reactivevalues.".

The proof-of-concept app.R that works;

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    
    selectInput("data_name", "Select data frame name:", choices = c("dataTable1", "dataTable2")),
    
    textInput("name", "Enter your name:", ""),
    
    numericInput("age", "Enter your age:", ""),
    
    actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    
    tableOutput("input_table")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- reactiveValues(
    dataTable1 = data.frame(Name = character(), Age = numeric()),
    dataTable2 = data.frame(Name = character(), Age = numeric())
  )
  
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    new_entry <- data.frame(Name = input$name, Age = input$age)
    data_name <- input$data_name
    data[[data_name]] <- rbind(data[[data_name]], new_entry)
  })
  
  
  output$input_table <- renderTable({
    data[[input$data_name]]
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The app.R that returns an error;

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
                 sidebarPanel(
                   selectInput("Operation", label = "Operation", choices = c("ENiG", "Autocatalytic_Sn", "Electroless_Cu", "Acid_Cu", "SnPb")),
                   dateInput("Date", label = "Date"),
                   textInput("Customer", label = "Customer", value = ""),
                   textInput("Job", label = "Job Number", value = ""),
                   selectInput("Size", label = "Panel Size", choices = c("18x12", "18x24")),
                   numericInput("QTY", label = "Quantity", value = 1),
                   numericInput("Load", label = "Load Count", value = 1),
                   selectInput("Surf", label = "surface Type", choices = c("Circuit Pattern", "Full Body", "Pads", "sheild", "Tabs")),
                   numericInput("Time", label = "Plating time... min", value = 1),
                   textInput("Operator", label = "Operator... Init/Name", value = ""),
                   textAreaInput("Comments", label = "Comments & Notes", value = ""),
                   actionButton("Submit", label = "Add Entry")
                 ),
                 
                 mainPanel(
                   
                   tableOutput("input_table")
                 ),
                 
                 position = c("right")
  )
)  
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    
    data <- reactiveValues(
      ENiG = data.frame(Operation = character(), Date = character(), Customer = character(), Job = character(),
                         Size = character(), QTY = numeric(), Load = numeric(), Surf = character(),
                         Time = numeric(), Operator = character(), Comments = character()),
      Autocatalytic_Sn = data.frame(Operation = character(), Date = character(), Customer = character(), Job = character(),
                         Size = character(), QTY = numeric(), Load = numeric(), Surf = character(),
                         Time = numeric(), Operator = character(), Comments = character()),
      Electroless_Cu = data.frame(Operation = character(), Date = character(), Customer = character(), Job = character(),
                                  Size = character(), QTY = numeric(), Load = numeric(), Surf = character(),
                                  Time = numeric(), Operator = character(), Comments = character()),
      Acid_Cu = data.frame(Operation = character(), Date = character(), Customer = character(), Job = character(),
                           Size = character(), QTY = numeric(), Load = numeric(), Surf = character(),
                           Time = numeric(), Operator = character(), Comments = character()),
      SnPb = data.frame(Operation = character(), Date = character(), Customer = character(), Job = character(),
                          Size = character(), QTY = numeric(), Load = numeric(), Surf = character(),
                          Time = numeric(), Operator = character(), Comments = character())
    )
    
    
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      new_entry <- data.frame(Operation = input$Operation , Date = input$Date, Customer = input$Customer,
                              Job = input$Job, Size = input$Size, QTY = input$QTY,
                              Load = input$Load, Surf = input$Surf, Time = input$Time,
                              Operator = input$Operator, Comments = input$Comments)
      Log_Name <- input$Operation
      data[[Log_Name]] <- rbind(data[[Log_Name]], new_entry)
    })
    
    
    output$input_table <- renderTable({
      data[[input$Log_Name]]
    })
  }
  
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Down in the code (rendering the table) you refer to `input$Log_Name` which doesn't exist in your UI. Did you mean `input$Operation` (which you assigned to variable `Log_Name` earlier in your code)?

Comment: No, Log_Name is just a variable that I pass Input$Operation to so that i can call the different tables based on the dynamic naming. the table with the same id as input$Operation selection is rendered for the fluid page.

Comment: I see my mistake now I thought I should be calling the variable name sort of like a 'paste' function but changing to input%Operation worked thank you I_O

Comment: Either `input$Operator` (or whichever input's value is desired) or assigning this value to a variable, e. g. `Log_Name` but within your `renderTable(...)` function.